# What is the past tense of “pathfinding”?

Tags: past-tense, conjugation

For context, pathfinding is a type of computer algorithm to find a path between two points.

I can see three likely answers to this question, and none of them feel great:

1. Pathfinded (weird because the past tense of *finding* is *found*)
2. Pathfound (sounds weird)
3. Pathed (sounds most correct, but it leaves out the *finding* part of the word)

Comment: What's your sentence? I don't think any of these are really viable.

Comment: @SteveBennett The NPC <pathfinding past tense> its way to the target.

Comment: I'd use "found" in that particular sentence.

Comment: _Pathfinding_ is a noun and has no tense.

Comment: Even if pathfind were a verb, I can't see that 'The NPC <pathfinding past tense> its way to the target.' would make sense. 'Found its way' is adequate.

Comment: Give us a few example sentences.

Comment: The NPC generated a path to its target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no past tense as "pathfinding" is a noun, not a verb. (Reference: [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pathfinding).)

You need to use a verb form to express past tense: "A path was found between the two points."

Comment: Welcome to ELU. We like answers to be authoritative, which means they need to be backed up by something. In this case a dictionary reference is good support, so I've added it for you.